# How do I arrange the value in ascending order which i'm passing the value for each segment of the UISegmentCotrol

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Here I created `UITextField` for entering the value and addButton to add that value in the segmentControl so for that I created resultSegment `(UISegmentControl)`.

Now let us assume if I insert value 50 in the textField and I click addButton then I insert 40 and I add it then finally I insert 45 value and add it so this values will insert in the segment as 50 40 45.
But I want this has to come in sorted way like ascending 40 45 50 like this.

can anyone plz help.
This is my code.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(97,     150, 200, 29)];
self.textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
self.textField.placeholder = @"Enter Numbers only";
self.textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:self.textField];


self.addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
self.addButton.frame = CGRectMake(310, 160, 20, 20);
[self.addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addingNum) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchDown)];
[self.view addSubview:self.addButton];


self.resultSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]init];
self.resultSegment.frame = CGRectMake(10, 200, 395, 29);
self.resultSegment.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.resultSegment];


self.refreshBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.refreshBtn.frame = CGRectMake(350, 160, 20, 20);
[self.refreshBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.refreshBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(removeAllSegments) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:self.refreshBtn];
}


-(void)addingNum
{
[self.resultSegment insertSegmentWithTitle:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.textField.text] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
}


-(void)removeAllSegments
{
    [self.resultSegment removeAllSegments];
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the compare selector to sort the array. Something like this:

```
self.resultSegment = [self.resultSegment sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: Can you mark this as the accepted answer if it helped you or let me know if it didn't please?